# ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action - IE11 - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I need my application to run in *Internet Explorer 11*, I thought this will be an easy job but I got stuck, I have tried different technics without any success, follow bellow the project stats:

```
"@angular/core": "5.2.10",
"webpack": "3.11.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4"

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

And in my "index.html" application I have added

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`.

Anyway, I tried everything and the application keeps displaying in the console the follow error in the *Internet Explorer 11*:

`ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action`

and

`ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]`.

In resume, I am lost and everything that I do can compromise another error to show, I thought that I am close to solve this but I have no idea where or what I am missing.

In the case that I got some help I will be very appreciative. Best regards.

Comment: Can you share your babel configuration?

Comment: Your webpack uses `babel-loader`, so you need to configure babel to transpile code for IE11. Pollyfills are not enough. They just make new API's work (like Map, Promise etc), not the new syntax (arrow functions, object spread, import/export etc)

Comment: I have put my code in the comments, as is seen *babel* for some reason is not been used in the project.